# Исходные данные React-Redux приложения

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, create-react-app

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ загружать приложение сразу с некими исходными данными полученными с сервера, а не подгружать их AJAX-ом в самом приложении?
Как вообще обычно это делается?

Comment: аяксом , а так в пропсах прописывай дефолтные, или в стор  initData

Comment: Я initData прописать могу на этапе написания приложения. А получить динамически сразу при загрузке приложения с сервера можно или только AJAX-ом уже в загруженном приложении?

Comment: да , только аяксом. можно извратится, написать например на сервере вставку в  html  скрипта с изначальными данными и  глобальной области видимости, но  это костыль.. проще аяксом запросить

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос выглядит неоднозначно. Вы хотите загружать приложение с данными, полученными с сервера, но не хотите подгружать данные в самом приложении. Коротким комментарием не получится дать ответ, поэтому напишу развернутый ответ.

Обычно это делается следующим образом (предположим, что у Вас уже устанолен React и приложение готово к запуску).

1. Создадим React-элемент, который будет простым компонентом без передаваемых в него `props`, но с начальным дефолтным состоянием `state`, описанным в конструкторе (сразу прибайндим наш метод получения данных `loadData`).

   ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       isLoading: true,
       error: null,
       data: [],
     };

     this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
   }
   ```
2. Наш компонент будет возвращать HTML в качестве результата. Опишем несколько результатов, предусматривающих наличие и отсутсвие необходимых данных, которые необходимо получить с сервера (в методе `render` будут простые проверки) - это так называемый [условный рендеринг](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

   ```
   render() {
     const { isLoading, data, error } = this.state;

     // Данные еще не были получены
     if (isLoading) {
       return <p>Loading data...</p>;
     }

     // Данные не получены, что-то пошло не так, ошибка
     if (error) {
       return <p>Error: {error}</p>;
     }

     // Данные успешно загружены и есть хотя бы одна запись
     if (data.length) {
       return <p>{data.length} data rows was loaded...</p>;
     }

     // Данные успешно загружены, но записей нет
     return <p>Data was loaded. No data to display...</p>;  
   }
   ```

   Всё достаточно просто. Примитивные проверки. Примитивная логика. Примитивный результат.
3. Метод `componentDidMount()` запускается после того, как компонент отрендерился в DOM - здесь мы и будем загружать данные. Никто не мешает сделать это в конструкторе, ведь конструктор компонента React вызывается до того, как компонент будет примонтирован. Однако мы определили состояние, а значит загрузку данных будем делать в методе  [`componentDidMount()`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) - это хорошее место для создания сетевых запросов.

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     // вызов метода загрузки данных `loadData`
     // хотя можно написать код из `loadData` прямо внутри `componentDidMount`
     this.loadData();
   }
   ```
4. Раз уж мы разделили метод загрузки данных и метод `componentDidMount`, то напишем примитивный пример кода метода загрузки данных (URL получения данных выдуманный):

   ```
   loadData() {
     fetch('https://api.example.com')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong...');
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ data, isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
   }
   ```

   Тут тоже всё просто, можно использовать `axios.get` для получения данных, можно через `fetch` - всё на Ваше усмотрение. Нужно обязательно проставить переменной `isLoading` значение `false`, чтобы *сказать* нашему приложению, что загрузка завершена. Это простой пример того, как обычно делается загрузка данных в React-приложении.

С Redux схема такая же, просто дергаете `action` загрузки данных, на который навешен `reducer`, затем через `mapStateToProps` достаете из стейта Redux-store необходимые данные и кладете в стейт Вашего компонента.